# Quel est le genre de « quelque chose » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre

> Elle est perfectionniste. Quand elle fait quelque chose, elle veut ____ faire aussi bien que possible.
>
> Je voulais vous dire quelque chose, mais je ne me ____ rappelle plus.

Devrait-on utiliser *le* ou *la* pour remplacer *quelque chose* dans ces phrases ? *Chose* est bien sûr féminin, mais *quelque chose* est un pronom, alors on doit utiliser *le* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quelque chose](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quelque_chose) est masculin singulier.

Donc on dit :

> Quand elle fait quelque chose, elle veut **le** faire ...

et pour la deuxième phrase (c'est la même chose pour masculin et féminin)

> Je ne m'**en** rappelle plus.

Pour celui-là, c'est un peu spécial. On peut dire "*se [rappeler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/se_rappeler) quelque chose*" (qui ferait "*je ne me **le** rappelle plus*") ou "*se rappeler **de** quelque chose*". Le deuxième est beaucoup plus courant.

Comment: [On prétend ici](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/se-rappeler-de-3/) que *se rappeler* se construit sans *de* si le complément est un nom. Qu'est-ce que tu en penses ?

Comment: Ça fait très littéraire, dans le langage courant c'est quasiment jamais utilisé. Tu le trouvera peut-être dans des livres, mais c'est tout.

Comment: Notons aussi l'expression "Cela manque d'un petit quelque chose..." qui démontre bien le genre masculin de ce mot.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat En effet, "se rappeler __de__ + nom" est très universellement utilisé, mais ça reste bien une grosse faute, qui personnellement me heurte chaque fois que je la lis ou l'entends...

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce cas, le référent n'est pas *chose*, mais *quelque chose*¹, qui est effectivement un pronom masculin singulier (voir par exemple [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose//1)). C'est donc bien **le** qui devrait être employé ici.

Pour la deuxième phrase, on peut aussi employer *en*

> Je ne m'en rappelle plus.

---

1. On est en présence de ce que les linguistes appellent « expression multi-mots », c'est-à-dire un lexème composé de plusieurs mots, mais dont le sens n'est pas directement dépendant du sens de ces mots². On ne peut pas dans ce cas traiter indépendament *quelque* et *chose*.
2. Voir par exemple [l'HDR de Matthieu Constant](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00841556/document) pour une étude assez complète de la question dans le cadre de l'analyse de texte.

Comment: [On prétend ici](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/se-rappeler-de-3/) que *se rappeler* se construit sans *de* si le complément est un nom. Qu'est-ce que tu en penses ?

Comment: @user11550 Étant de nature descriptiviste, je me suis arrêté au deuxième paragraphe “*J’ai pu  constater à quel point ces façons de faire étaient loin d’être respectées, même  par de bons auteurs. […] le Petit Robert la dit  « très répandue »; le  Larousse, « très courante » […] cette  construction, « sans cesse combattue par les pédagogues, est très vivante dans l’usage spontané*”. Si c'est courant c'est que cela fait partie de la langue. D'autant que si c'est employé par de « bons auteurs » il y a peu de chance que cela porte préjudice à celui qui l'emploierait.